# Is alpha-linolenic acid used by the human body for anything other than conversion to EPA?

Tags: dha-docosahexaenoic-acid, epa-eicosapentaenoic-acid

As a slightly different question: Does ALA have any beneficial effect on the human body apart from its conversion to EPA (and then to DHA)?

Comment: What has your research revealed so far?